# org.koin.android.error.MissingAndroidContextException: when try to test app with context

Tags: android, koin

I want to write test for `koin`. I use `RoomDatabase`, which receives context in constructor. App works well but test fails

> Can't resolve Application instance. Please use androidContext()
>   function in your KoinApplication configuration.

Answer (score 7):

**if you want context in your modules, you should pass context in your start koin method**

```
// start Koin!
    startKoin {

      // declare used Android context
      androidContext(this@MyApplication)

      // declare modules
      modules(yourModule)
    }
```

**and use these libraries**

```
    // Koin AndroidX Scope features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-scope:2.0.1"
// Koin AndroidX ViewModel features
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1'
// Koin AndroidX Experimental features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-ext:2.0.1"
```

Comment: in my case, it does not work, have you experienced this?

Comment: so again you got the same error after using new koin libraries? can you post your error log? with your qtn

Comment: org.koin.android.error.MissingAndroidContextException: Can't resolve Context instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration.

Comment: i give the answer according to your exception that shown in the question..i think your module definition gets wrong.please make sure that context passed correctly

Comment: startKoin{
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
            modules(appModule)
        }

Comment: val appModule = module {
    single <Dao>{ GameProcessDataBase.getInstance(androidContext()).gameProcesDao()}
}

Comment: single { GameProcessDataBase.getInstance(androidApplication()) }  and define your dao in database class..it will work perfectly

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to set your context when you start koin. Then you should be able to access it via androidContext() in your modules.

```
startKoin {
    androidContext(this@App)
    modules(...)
    ...
}
```

Comment: in my case, it does not work, have you experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

For unittests I have implemented this

```
@file:JvmName("KoinTest")
package com.myapp.di

import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin

fun startKoin() {
    startKoin {
        androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
        modules(listOf(applicationModule, networkModule))
    }
}

fun stopKoin() {
    org.koin.core.context.stopKoin()
}
```

I can call this from our old Java tests as `KoinTest.startKoin()` or just `startKoin()` in Kotlin. I call these from the `@Before` and `@After` block appropriately. The android context is set with the new AndroidX test library function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test Room in unit testing with Koin. You can only test in instrumented tests.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I edit my application class to :

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {

            androidContext(this@App)

            modules(viewModelModule)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

KOIN : 3.2.0-beta-1

```
// Koin Core features
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0-beta-1"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.2.0-beta-1"
```

declare context under startkoin like below

```
androidContext(this@KoinSampleApplication)
```

---

```
class KoinSampleApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoinDI()
}

private fun startKoinDI() {
    startKoin {

        // declare context
        androidContext(this@KoinSampleApplication)

        // declare modules
        modules(
            networkModule,
            repositoryModule,
            servicesModule,
            utilityModule,
            viewModelModule,
        )

    }
    }
}
```

---

Hope it will work.